# Git diff parse using grep shell command

Tags: git, bash, shell

git diff

```
diff --git a/lids b/lids
index 009d7e8..46447a8 100644
--- a/lids
+++ b/lids
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
-FP CA1 CAPS Mapping.pdf
 mtool1428_100squaretool.html
+mtool1428_100squaretool.py
 Lesson Guide 100square 23LessonIdeas.pdf
 Worksheet 100square 0to99.pdf
 Worksheet 100square 1to100.pdf
 Worksheet 100square Blank.pdf
-Worksheet 100square Challenge 1.pdf
-Worksheet 100square Challenge 2.pdf
+Worksheet 100square Challenge 11.pdf
 Worksheet 100square Challenge 3.pdf
+Worksheet 100square Challenge 2.pdf
 Worksheet 100square Challenge 4.pdf
 Worksheet 100square Challenge 5.pdf
 Worksheet 100square Challenge 6.pdf
```

How to grep deleted strings starting with a single - sign and string starting with single + sign

Comment: __Don't__, don't attempt to filter lines from the `diff` in this manner.  (Did you notice the lines containing the filenames that start with `---` and `+++`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to grep deleted strings starting with a single - sign and string starting with single + sign

You can use this egrep:

```
grep '^ *[-+][a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

OR this:

```
grep '^ *[-+][[:alnum:]]'
```

OR this:

```
grep '^ *[-+][^-+]'
```

Comment: yeah I missed it... Thanks anubhava

Comment: You could do `[^+-]` as well, instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to say "only a single + or - sign"

Comment: @rabin: May I know what was wrong with my answer here that you had to remove acceptance mark?

Comment: I want to give acceptance to both of the answers..... so while giving acceptance to another answer, yours was unchecked, which i noticed just now.....i have accepted it again...thanks for pointing (lesson learnt.. only one  answer can be accepted :)

Comment: Yes that's true only one is accepted (usually first and correct one). You can always upvote the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following command shows lines with '-' or '+' from the beginning of each line that are not followed by '-' or '+'

```
git diff <file> | grep ^[-+][^-+]
```

Comment: Working nicely...Thanks Luis